# ngFor and (click) event Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular 2 RC4 with Typescript. My problem is thant: I want to get an object from the array of objects when I click on the name of the needed object. My ts code is:

```
import { CategoryClass } from '../../category/class/category.class';
import { ComponentClass } from '../class/component.class';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './app/inventory/component/add/add.component.html'
})
export class AddComponent {
    private ClientData: ComponentClass = {
        ComponentId: 0,
        ComponentCategory: 0
    };
    private ServerCategorys: CategoryClass[] = [
        { CategoryId: 0, CategoryName: 'N/A', CategoryNote: 'N/A' }
    ];

    private getSingleCategory(_category: CategoryClass): void {
        this.ClientData.ComponentCategory = _category.CategoryId;
        console.log(this.ClientData.ComponentCategory);
    }
}
```

My HTML code is:

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="exampleSelect1" class="col-xs-2 col-form-label">Category</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
        <option></option>
        <option *ngFor="let category of ServerCategorys" (click)="getSingleCategory(category)">{{category?.CategoryName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I watched the consol log and I didn't saw the ClientData.ComponentCategory value, I tryed to put an break point and the application never stoped when I arrived to it. So I suppose that I never call the getSingleCategory function. Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `(click)` on `<option>`.

Instead set `(change)` on `<select>` element just to be notified when the value changes and also use `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` to easily get the current value:

```
<select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="getSingleCategory()">
    <option *ngFor="let category of ServerCategorys" [value]="category">{{category?.CategoryName}}</option>
</select>

export class AddComponent {
    selectedValue = null;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You can also use Typescript Property Accessors to make selectedValue a property, and trigger getSingleCategory() from the setter - prevents the need for listening to the change event.  See [this plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/UErCcJeX5ply1BXSjweY/).  Basically: 
`private localSelected : string;  `
`set selectedValue(value: string): void {` 
`    this.localSelected = value; `
`    this.getSingleCategory(); };` 
`get selectedValue(): any { return this.localSelected; }`

Answer (score 0):

You want the `(change)` event when they select an option.

```
<option *ngFor="let category of ServerCategorys" (change)="getSingleCategory(category)">
    {{category?.CategoryName}}
</option>
```